# Pixabay API CORB issue

Tags: javascript, security, fetch-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am getting Cross-Origin Read-Blocking (CORB) when trying to access the Pixabay API from within my JavaScript (React) app.

[image: CORB issue]

Here is my fetch code:

```
fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${API_KEY}&q=travel&image_type=photo&pretty=true`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    result => {
      console.log(result);
      // set url array in state to be used by a gallery component..
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

The fetch returns the data fine but the each of the individual image urls used in a simple img tag throws a CORB error.

What do I need to do to unblock my request?

Comment: Based on a test I just ran, and on the screenshot you posted, I can tell that there is no problem with the API request (it returns 20 hits, and as you can see in your screenshot, there are exactly 20 CORB issues, so you're parsing the results successfully). The issue is probably what you do with those results afterwards. Please post the relevant code. And click on the little arrow next to `20` to see what URLs are the source of the problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick response blex :) I have updated the question, I hope it is enough info

Comment: It seems that any pixabay url i use, even hardcoded into an img tag will show this error..

Comment: Does the API set a cookie which is needed for subsequent requests perhaps? Couldn't find much about this in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using the links to Pixabay's website as src for your images (`hit.pageURL`). Didn't you mean to use `hit.previewURL`?

```
const API_KEY = '123456789abcdef';

fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${API_KEY}&q=travel&image_type=photo&pretty=true`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    result => {
      // Just for the demo
      const html = result.hits.map(
        hit => `<a href="${hit.pageURL}"><img src="${hit.previewURL}"></a>`
      ).join('');
      document.body.innerHTML = html;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Wahoo! Thanks man, good spot. I just learned something today :) I was aware of all the options for each image but didn't think each field would have a different level of security, all makes sense now..